# Fluid Width / CSS issue

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I am attempting to layout a site:

http://kenzshop.com/Brandon/index

I cannot get the main content area (blue colored)to align correctly.

The header (red) has a fluid with, the sidebar (yellow) has a fluid height, the main content area should be fluid width and height, but I cannot figure out how to get it to align correctly.

It should align width-wise with the header.

Can anyone see what my issue is?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>Title of document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xhtml; charset=utf-8"></meta>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/css; charset=utf-8"></meta>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="main"><!--<iframe src="http://www.cnn.com/"/> --></div>
   <div id="sidebar"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%; 
}

#header{
   height: 80px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding: 5px;
   margin-top: 5px;
   margin-left: 5px;
   margin-right: 5px;
   background-color:red;
}

#main{
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   top:90px;
   right: 263px;
   padding:0;
   margin-top: 12px;
   margin-left: 5px;
   margin-bottom:5px;
   height:99% !important; /* works only if parent container is assigned a height value */
   width:100%;
   border:1px solid black;
   background-color:blue;
}

iframe{
   margin: 5px;
   display:block; 
   width:100%!important; 
   height:100%!important;
}

#sidebar{
   position:absolute;
   right:0;
   top:102px;
   padding:0;
   margin-right:5px;
   margin-bottom:5px;
   width:250px;
   height:99%; /* works only if parent container is assigned a height value */
   border:1px solid black;
   background-color:yellow;
}
```

[image: instructions]

Comment: Can you give me more details about what it means to "align correctly" ?

Comment: Just uploaded an image to show better ;) Thanks, Ken

Comment: As an aside, new web pages should not be using the transitional doctype. Transitional is for those pages which contain older deprecated markup while transitioning to strict. But you should not be using deprecated markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since their are little to no variables, this is easily solved by relying on `position: absolute`, without affecting flexibility.

The HTML:

```
<header class="header"></header>

<div class="content">
    <iframe src="http://www.cnn.com/"></iframe>
</div>

<div class="sidebar"></div>
```

The CSS:

```
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header,
.content,
.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.header {
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px; 
    left: 5px; 
    height: 80px;
    background: red;
}

.content,
.sidebar {
    top: 90px;
    bottom: 5px;
}

.content {
    left: 5px;
    right: 260px;
}

.content iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
    right: 5px;
    width: 250px; 
    background: green;
}
```

Take a look at it here: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/WBRCj/
    ​

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much JOPLOmacedo :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

HTML:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="main"></div>
<div id="sidebar"></div>​
```

CSS:

```
​#header {
    height: 60px;
    background: red;
    margin-bottom: 10px
}
#main {
    width: 68%;
    background: blue;
    float: left;
    height: 800px;
}
#sidebar {
    width: 30%;
    background:yellow;
    float: right;
    height: 800px;
}​
```

And the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jHnWp/)

P.S. Wasn't sure whether to base it off your current site, or your image posted, as both seem to follow different concepts.  Did image for now.

Comment: The main and sidebar height's should be fluid. Changing those both from 800px to 100% won't work will it?

Comment: I edited the site (and code above) to look closer to the image now, didn't even realize the header wasn't spanning the whole page :/

Comment: All that really needs to be done is to get the right side of the main area (blue) aligned with the header above it, width-wise) and still be fluid.